# Suppose that $f(x)= xg(x)$ for some function $g$ which is continuous at $0$. Prove that $f$ is differentiable at 0 , and find $f'(0)$ in terms of $g$.

Tags: calculus

> Suppose that $f(x)= xg(x)$ for some function $g$ which is continuous at $0$. Prove that $f$ is differentiable at 0 , and find $f'(0)$ in terms of $g$.

Okay, so far I have:
$$f(x) = x g(x) \quad \Longrightarrow \quad g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x}$$

So, $f(x) = \frac{x \cdot f(x)}{x}$.

Since $g$ is continuous at $0$, $f$ is differentiable at $0$.

Is that all I would need to say to answer the question?
The second part, would I apply the quotient rule to $g$?  We are not allowed to use $g'$.

$$f'(x) = \frac{x(xf'(x) - 1 \cdot f(x)) - x f(x) \cdot 1}{x^2}$$

Am I headed in the right direction?

Comment: You may want to click "edit" and see how I changed everything to use LaTeX.  It's desirable to use LaTeX on Math.SE as opposed to typing out your equations with ascii.  P.S. If you feel anything you said was lost in my translation, feel free to edit it to the way you prefer.

Comment: I have made some formatting changes to make this more readable.  I hope that it reflects your original intent.

Comment: Your statement "Since g is continuous at 0, f is differentiable at 0 " is not correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint** To prove that $f$ is differentiable at $0$, you need to prove that the following limit exists

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} \,.$$

What is $f(0)$?

Can you see any connection between your limit and $g$? If yes, what is this limit?

Comment: So the Limit of x->0 is g(x)-f(0)?

Comment: @pete Well, what is $f(0)$?