# Suppose $f$ is differentiable at zero and $f(0) = 0$. Show that $f(x) = xg(x)$

Tags: calculus

> Suppose $f$ is differentiable at zero and $f(0) = 0$. Show that $f(x) = xg(x)$.

We have $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{f(x)}{x} = c$. How can I show that there must exist a function $g(x)$ such that $g(x)x = f(x)$?

Comment: Why do you infer that $g$ is continuous? It need not even be continuous at zero. It must have a limit at zero. That's all.

Comment: @user19405892 To begin with, any function $f$ such that $f(0)=0$ can be written as $f(x)=xg(x)$ for some function $g$, because $f(x)/x$ exists for all $x\ne0$ and $g(0)$ can be chosen arbitrarily. Your first suggestion that any such $g$ must be continuous at $0$ when $f'(0)$ exists is therefore false. However, it is true that, if $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)$ exists, then there exists a function $g$ continuous at $0$ such that $f(x)=xg(x)$ for all $x$, and, in particular it must hold $g(0)=f'(0)$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Why is that the case?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp I was talking to the poster.

Comment: @user19405892 Why is that the case of what? I said four things.

Comment: Simple counterexample: f(x) = x, g(x) = 1 for $x\neq 0$ and $g(0) = 2$.

Answer (score 1):

If you want $g$ continue, write $g(x) = {{f(x)}\over x}$ if $x\neq 0$ and$g(0)=f'(0)$. $lim_{x\rightarrow 0}g(x)=lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{{f(x)}\over x}=f'(0)$. So $g$ is continue.

Remark that here $f(x)=xg(x)$.

Comment: Do you have a math reason why my argument is not true?

Comment: I deleted it. Sorry. However, I insist that in the original post $g$ needs not be continuous.

Comment: @Tsemoaristide How do you know that there exists a function $g(x)$ such that $f(x) = xg(x)$? You seem to be assuming there exists one already.

Comment: He defines it..

Comment: Please read, before asking question, the function g is defined

Comment: @TsemoAristide The question says "Show that $f(x) = xg(x)$." It is not given.

Comment: Op does not mention that g has to be continuous in the question, but he talks about the continuity of g in the comments after the question. It for this I start with:" if you want g to be continuous,..."

Comment: @TsemoAristide I am confused by your argument. The point of the question is to show that we can write $f(x) = xg(x)$ but that is the first thing you wrote.

Comment: @TsemoAristide +1 Thank you. I am reading too fast.

Comment: @user19405892: Tselmo's answer is the obvious and canonical one. And it is correct. You should sit and think about it until you understand it.

Comment: @user19405892 You want such a function $g$, right? So, you will have to define it. And that is what Tsemo did. He defined $g(x) := f(x)/x$ for $x\neq 0$ and $g(0) := f'(0)$. That is a definition. Now, you only have to check that $f(x) = xg(x)$ with that function $g$ just defined.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Oh, I see. It is just those extra conditions that had to be checked.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ a function fuch that $f(0)=0$ (as the question stands, you don't need *any* hypothesis of regularity).

Pick any real number $\alpha$. Consider the function $$g(x)=\begin{cases}\alpha&\text{if }x=0\\\frac{f(x)}{x}&\text{if }x\ne 0\end{cases}$$

Then, $$xg(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x=0\\f(x)&\text{if }x\ne 0\end{cases}$$
So $f(x)=xg(x)$ holds for all $x\ne0$. But since $f(0)=0$, equality holds for $x=0$ as well.

**In case details of continuity pop out:** See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349407/suppose-that-fx-xgx-for-some-function-g-which-is-continuous-at-0-pro?rq=1).